# all-auth SMTPAuthentication Error

Tags: django, smtp, django-allauth, django-settings

I'm getting `SMTPAuthenticationError at /rest-auth/password/reset/` error.

I'm using all-auth-rest and set these on settings.py

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'randomemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 25 # or 587
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
```

Also I enabled `Displaying an Unlock Captcha` and allowed `less secure app access`

What is missing?

Thanks

Comment: what your `EMAIL_BACKEND`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This configurations is if you work with `smtp.gmail.com`, other smtp is similiar with this configuration.

1. Unlock Captha: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
2. Change to active: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

---

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your_gmail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your_password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

I think you missed: `EMAIL_BACKEND`

Comment: Great! Why don't you try to answer this question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842995/facebook-and-unregistered-user-all-auth

Comment: I never use that plugin... maybe the return the calback but I'm not sure..

Comment: OK! THanks anyway